# What is Java's 'self' keyword

Tags: java, php, oop

I'm trying to write a factory method in an abstract class in Java (so I want it to return a new instance of the extending class, rather than the super-class).

In PHP I'd do this using the `self` keyword:

```
abstract class Superclass {
    public static function factory($arg) {
        return new self($arg);
    }

    private function __construct($arg) {}

    abstract public function doSomething() {}
}
```

Does Java have a keyword like `self` I can use for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No; in Java, static methods are not inherited in the same way as non-static methods are. A subclass will have the static methods of its superclass, but when they execute, they will execute in context of the superclass - so there is no keyword that can be used in static methods to find out what class the method was invoked through.

Edit: A more precise formulation is that static methods are not inherited at all; however, the language allows us to use `Subclass.foo()` to call the static method `Superclass.foo()`.

Based on what you seem to want to achieve, you might want to implement the [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). It goes approximately like this:

```
public abstract class Superclass {}
public class SubclassA extends Superclass {}
public class SubclassB extends Superclass {}

public abstract class AbstractFactory {
    public abstract Superclass Create();
}

public class FactoryA extends AbstractFactory {
    public Superclass Create() {
        return new SubclassA();
    }
}

public class FactoryB extends AbstractFactory {
    public Superclass Create() {
        return new SubclassB();
    }
}
```

Now, you can e.g. create a method that takes an `AbstractFactory` (which, in reality, will be either a `FactoryA` or a `FactoryB`). Calling `Create()` on this object will produce either a `SubclassA` or a `SubclassB`.

Edit: Fixed compilation error (forgot to make the factories extend `AbstractFactory`).

Comment: @Ross: Perhaps - in what contexts do you need to create the instances (why did you need that method instead of just using the subclass constructors directly)? Do you ever need to create instances without knowing in advance what kind of class you will need? If so, see the update for code samples about the Abstract Factory pattern; otherwise, that pattern is probably way overkill. :-)

Comment: I understood that the whole point is to make the thing dynamic.

Comment: @tada: Please explain; where did I contradict myself? (I suggested the Abstract Factory pattern because that's what I thought he wanted to achieve, but then I realized that maybe he had some other intention, so I just wanted to make it clear that that pattern is only useful in certain situations. Or are you thinking about something else?)

Comment: @tada: Ah; I suppose you are referring to my downvote of the answer containing a compilation error; I have now fixed the error (at least the one I could spot).

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely **have to** you can use this code form a static context:

```
Class cls = new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
Object instance = cls.newInstance();
```

Your class need to have a nullary constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need some hacks to achieve this. One way I can think of to obtain this is:

```
public static <T extends SuperClass> T factory(Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in Java to find out the name of the "current" subclass. And especially some dynamic object generation won't be possible.

So you'll need to define that static function in every subclass instead.